# I got first class or a first class in my exam

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context, sentence-construction, articles, usage

When we were studying Intermediate,  we used to say that "I got first class in my Tenth class public Examination". Our English lecturer would repeatedly correct us by saying that" I got a first class in my Tenth class public examination" stressing the use of article in the sentence.I want to know whether the use of article a is necessary or not in the sentence.

Comment: American here, so I will not actually answer and defer to the Brits - but it looks from online search as though either "received first class honors" or "received a first-class" are in use, whereas "received first-class" is not.

Comment: I wrote an answer based around the grades for honours degrees, but then I realised that these are grades for school exams, taken at age 16, and so this is an Indian idiom, not a British one.  Education systems and their jargon are notoriously diverse, and everybody assumes that the grading system used in their country will be understood worldwide.

Comment: Yes, specifying the exam and country would help clarify, as these things vary a lot.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Generally the article "a" is preferred.  But omitting it is such a minor error that I wouldn't bother to correct it in a student.

> I got an A-star in French. (UK A-levels 18+)

> I got a nine in Art.  (UK GCSE 16+)

> I got a GPA of 4.0 in my senior year. (US High School and college)

> I got a starred distinction. (UK vocational qualifications)

> I got a first class in Hindi. (Indian Standard and Highers)

(These all represent the highest achievement)

For the UK university system, you would say

> I got a first. (UK university)

You don't use "a" when giving a measured mark or percentage

> I got 75 per cent

> I got 12 out of 20.

Comment: Thank you so much Mr James for your timely and useful explanation. You always explain well

Comment: You're welcome.  Not Mr James, James is my first name.  One doesn't use Mr with first names (in normal contexts).  (and not "sir" either, I strongly dislike being called "sir") Plain "James" is fine.

Comment: Can we use Mr With our Second name? This is something new for me and no native speaker hasn't asked me not to use Mr with the first name. I know the use of sir even for teachers. They don't like formal greetings

Comment: That may be worth a separate question, but yes,  use Mr/Ms with surnames.

Comment: See https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/124814/if-you-only-know-the-name-of-someone-is-it-ok-to-call-him-mr-john-or-ms-jane

Comment: I will add a potential exception to this. As an American, when specifically talking about school grades measured in percent, I *would* in fact say "I got a 75", "I got a 75%", or "I got 75%" all interchangeably. I would not, however, say "I got 75".